# Как Telegram или VK проводят синхронизацию?

Tags: javascript

Меня мучает проблема синхронизации.

У меня на сайте работает сокет, поэтому мне важно узнать, какие данные мне пришли за то время, что я был оффлайн или мой ноутбук был во сне. *(Важно знать, что соединение у меня не стабильно и может отключаться на 0.2-0.4с, но синхранизацию это запускать не должно, иначе бы я использовал события сокета)*

Тем не менее, что бы я не делал, ничего не получается. Пробовал варианты с **интервалом** (сохраняем метку, если текущая больше сохраненной на n-сек, то значит, что мы были во сне), с **xhr** запросами (следил за их статусами и сохранял метки в нужный момент), с **сокетом** и кучей других способов, но так или иначе они работали либо частично, либо через раз.

Поэтому хочу узнать, как делают такое tg или vk, или может предложите свой вариант?

Comment: Все упомянутые способы работают и активно используются в разных проектах. Если у вас "они работали либо частично, либо через раз" - значит вы сами что-то криво сделали

Comment: @andreymal можешь тогда прикрепить пример такого метода? Я тоже думаю, что что-то делаю не правильно, но не могу понять где